# choose condition to display table in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to hide a table in a jsp page when a condition is true and display if otherwise. I am using the below format to do this:

```
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="condition ">
            <tr> <td align="center" ><font color="red"><b><fmt:message key=" message here "/></b></font></td></tr>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
<center>
    <table class="bordered">


    </table>

</center>
    </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
```

I tried using many solutions given here on this forum. But none have worked. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong..

Comment: can you please provide condition you wrote in `c:choose` ? And which table is showing ?

Comment: <c:when test="${actionBean.status == 'ACTIVE' }">
                                                       <tr> <td align="center" ><font color="red"><b><fmt:message key="message"/></b></font></td></tr>
                                                </c:when>

Comment: I t would be good if you post you complete jsp page and the controller from where you are sending `actionBean` !